# ntpd -qg: Use with timeout

Tags: bash, timeout, raspberry-pi3, ntp

working on Pi3

**Situation**: only one server in `/etc/ntp.conf` is given and this given address is invalid (no NTP-Server running on that address).

**Problem**: running `ntpd -qg` does never end, since there is no timeout like in `ntpdate -t 60`.

**Question**: Can one specify a timeout for `ntpd`? If not, how can you assure the process ends after time x?

For now on startup the pi executes a bash-script that tries to get actual time from given NTP-Server in `/etc/ntp.conf` and then hangs in the process since there is no NTP-Server available on that address. So the process is running from start and i can't call another `ntpd` until the initial `ntpd`-process is killed.

Any work around?

PS: I would like not to use ntpdate since it is tagged as a retiring package

---

**EDIT:**

The RPi3 is located in an isolated network. Online NTP-servers are no option in my case.

Comment: Which server are you configuring in your /etc/ntp.conf to sinchronize the date? If its an external server, why don't you set a different ONLINE server?

Comment: The server I am using is one in an isolated network (pi is in that network too). In the normal case the given address HAS an NTP-Server running. So using an online server is not an option.

Comment: Is that local server properly configured? Is it working fine? Can you ping to the IP of that NTP-server from your pi?

Comment: The case i wanted to look at was when the NTP-Server is misconfigured. It was about the timeout, not the configuration of the NTP-Server. Thx anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `timeout` command usually shipped with coreutils that allows you to set timeout on any command (even if it does not support it on its own). E.g.

```
timeout 60 ntpd -qg
```

To run run `ntpd -qg` and have it time out after 60s. If the command finished, you should get its return value, if the `timeout` intervened, you get 124.